# XMPPFramework creating multiple login in iOS app

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I have implemented chat using XMPPFramework but a new requirement has cropped up as explained below:-

There should be multiple login using different avatars of same user.Its same as supporting multiple login at the same time from same app where user can chat and switch between his different accounts. I think creating multiple stream and calling connect on them is the solution but i am having doing the same.

Please provide guidance on how to create multiple chat stream and use them in parallel.

**UPDATE** :- like Xabber android app's multiple account support

Comment: Why do you say "singletons like roster?" XMPPFramework allows you to construct multiple `XMPPStream` objects and multiple `XMPPRoster` objects.

Comment: @RobNapier any pointers in the direction would be helpful

Comment: I don't understand the question. Create another `XMPPStream` object and connect with it just like the first one. What "singleton" are you talking about? XMPPRoster is not a singleton. https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Core/XMPPStream.h  https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Extensions/Roster/XMPPRoster.h

Comment: Thanku actually the current implementation is replica of a tutorial creating a shared xmppcontroller.roster is not singleton.

Comment: What have you tried? (whathaveyoutried.com) There is no simple answer to "how do I develop a multi-account XMPP app." That's a whole product (I developed one for years). Can you narrow your question to some specific problem you're having? Creating multiple streams is absolutely trivial. Create two `XMPPStream` objects. So I assume you have some other specific problem. Have you started with the XMPPFramework book? https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/eBook

Comment: Thank you for the link will definitely take a look XMPPFramework is not my forte(i work on chess apps) its my first time i know the basics but this app has already kept xmppstream in singleton so changing it to multiple login was creating trouble.

Comment: XMPP is a very complicated protocol. If you're going to work on it, you will definitely need to study how it works first. XMPPFramework assumes you already know a lot about XMPP. For example, it assumes you understand the difference between Core and XEPs, how rosters work, etc. RFC3920 and RFC3921 are absolutely must-reads before you proceed, and then regular reference to the XEP documents: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/ But it sounds like your primary issues are related to refactoring this program, not XMPP itself (yet).

Comment: Will there be any problem when creating multiples of XMPPStream objects? Why is it much complicated as you said above? Me also trying to configure gtalk and jabber client, so have to maintain multiples of xmppstream object. Just curious, before dive into workaround.

Comment: creating multiple streams and maintaining there reference is not that hard tough part is maintaining chat and friend lists etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes I just tried. Multiple reference of streams is just working fine for maintaining user session, chat and presence.